# UIPickerView UIButton in viewForRow doesn't respond

Tags: iphone, sdk, uibutton, uipicker

Button doesn't respond in viewForRow:

```
UIView * rowView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)] autorelease];

UIButton* deleteButton = [[[UIButton alloc]init]autorelease];
deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, 10, 20,20);
[deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IconTrash.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[deleteButton addTarget: self action:@selector(removeCellAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UILabel *labelText = [[UILabel alloc]init];
labelText.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[localFlagNotes objectAtIndex:row] value]];
labelText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size: 24];
labelText.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 200, 28);
labelText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[rowView addSubview:labelText];
[rowView addSubview:deleteButton];
[labelText release];
return rowView;
```

`removeCellAtIndexPath` doesn't call after press button. Does anyone have some idea why and some solution?

I think button even not pressed only cell become active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find ways.  just in

```
- (UIView*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickersView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
     {
           PickerCustomView * rowView = [[PickerCustomView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 310, 50) withText:[[localFlagNotes objectAtIndex:row] value]] ;
           rowView.delegate = self;
           return rowView;
     }
```

Create custom View with button

Like this

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withText:(NSString*)text
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) 
{
     deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];

    [deleteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IconTrash"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(250, 10, 35,35);

    textLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    originText = text;
    NSString *trimmed = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    textLabel.text =  trimmed;
    textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size: 24];
    textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 230, 28);
    textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self addSubview:textLabel];
    [self addSubview:deleteButton];      

}
return self;
```

}

And use:

```
-(void)deleteButtonAction:(id)sender
 {
     [delegate removeCellAtIndexPath:originText];
 }
```

Or:

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    if ( (location.x > 10 && location.x < 38) && (location.y > 240 && location.y < 265)    )
     {
        [self deleteButtonAction:nil];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your deleteButtonUr button's frame(width) exceeds the rowView's frame.so increase the view's frame as like,

```
UIView * rowView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)] autorelease];
```

otherwise adjust the label and deleteButton's frame with in your rowView's frame

Comment: Tnx my mistake))  now i can press button... but selector doesnt call

Comment: -(void) removeCellAtIndexPath:(NSString*)text

Comment: U cant send string as parameter i think

Comment: no I create -(void)deleteButtonClick:(id)sender but this  dont call too

Comment: Do like this.It will definitely work.
[deleteButton addTarget: self action:@selector(deleteButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: ))) i am noob in programming but  i change selector in target

Comment: Oops!!! u r spking abt pickerViewCell.I tht of tableViewCell.Am not sure abt pickerView Dude.till  now I just added label only in pickerView.Am not sure abt button click dude ;)

Comment: ok i try 
 UIButton* deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

      deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(210,10,60,30.0);
    [deleteButton setTitle:@"delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deleteButton addTarget: self action:@selector(deleteButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: and nothink i thin its imposible